# Notify me when the Flash movie is done playing

Tags: javascript, flash, callback, dom-events, swfobject

I'm new to working with flash and have a quick question about embedding Flash with the SWFObject.js file.

I can successfully embed an object and play it, but what I'd like to know now is if there is a way that I can be notified when the movie is done being played without editing the flash file itself, since I have no real way to do that.

Is there a callback or an event that I could somehow connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this without editing the source, which would be a very simple change if you could do it.

The reason, as far as I can guess, as to why no such callback event exists is there would be no real logical place to have the event fired.  Imagine a timeline animation that gets to the last frame and says stop().  Is that done?  What if I can still click on buttons within the movie that allow me to do other things... or if the final frame just has a delayed function call to do something else, like restart.  There is no "END" to a flash movie, unless you make it so there is one yourself.

Comment: This is what I thought, I just wanted to make sure.